# MySQL says "Cannot add foreign key constraint" and I cannot find the reason why

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE Nutzer (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Nutzername VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
Passwort VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
Vorname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Nachname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Geburtstag DATETIME NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Land (
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Text TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Highlight (
Highlight_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Titel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Info VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Highlight_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Highlight (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Rezension (
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
Titel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Text TEXT NOT NULL,
Datum DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Bild (
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Inhalt BLOB NOT NULL,
Info VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Bild_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE RezSchreiben (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID, Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Rezension_ID) REFERENCES Rezension (Rezension_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE LandBewerten (
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Rezension_ID,Landname),
FOREIGN KEY Rezension_ID REFERENCES Rezension (Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Landname REFERENCES Land (Landname)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE LandHigh (
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Highlight_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Landname, Highlight_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Landname REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY Highlight_ID REFERENCES Highlight (Highlight_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Favorisieren (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID, Landname),
FOREIGN KEY Nutzer_ID REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Landname REFERENCES Land (Landname)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE BildHinzufügen (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Bild_ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Nutzer_ID REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Bild_ID REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE  RezBild (
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Rezension_ID, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Rezension_ID REFERENCES Rezension (Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Bild_ID REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE LandBild (
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Landname, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Landname REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY Bild_ID REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE HighBild (
Highlight_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Highlight_ID, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Highlight_ID REFERENCES Highlight (Highlight_ID),
FOREIGN KEY Bild_ID REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Can you add the error message please. BTW you need to create the referenced tables before the tables which reference them

Comment: The only error I get is "#1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint". And I'm sorry, I'm new to mysql, what is here the referenced table exactly?

Comment: nutzer has FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID), the referenced table is bild and therefore bild must be created before nutzer. The fk error will tell you the fk at fault.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice :) I'm gonna test that

Comment: I added the tables without the FK's and then I tried to add them via "ALTER TABLE Nutzer ADD FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname)" but i get the error "1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails". What is the failure?

Comment: If your table engines are the same (hopefully innodb) there is nothing wrong with the alter statement (it does work for me)

Comment: also check your primary key definition, you defined an auto_increment to start to 1 but you haven't set the primary key to auto increment. If the value for the primary key is not set, it will always be 0 and you will eventually hit a duplicate entry error for the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referencing to a foreign key, the field/column on the table should have the same type & attributes with the referenced table.

For the example below:

```
    CREATE TABLE Land (
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Text TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

You defined Bild_ID as a foreign key reference to Bild.Bild_ID, but you didn't create the actual column itself. Here is the full query below fixing the said issues:

```
    CREATE TABLE Bild (
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Inhalt BLOB NOT NULL,
Info VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Bild_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Land (
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Text TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Nutzer (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Nutzername VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
Passwort VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
Vorname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Nachname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Geburtstag DATETIME NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;



CREATE TABLE Highlight (
Highlight_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Titel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Info VARCHAR(255),
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Highlight_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Rezension (
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
Titel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Text` TEXT NOT NULL,
Datum DATETIME NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;



CREATE TABLE RezSchreiben (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID, Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Rezension_ID) REFERENCES Rezension (Rezension_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE LandBewerten (
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Rezension_ID,Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Rezension_ID) REFERENCES Rezension (Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE LandHigh (
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Highlight_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Landname, Highlight_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Highlight_ID) REFERENCES Highlight (Highlight_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE Favorisieren (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID, Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE BildHinzufügen (
Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Bild_ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE  RezBild (
Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Rezension_ID, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Rezension_ID) REFERENCES Rezension (Rezension_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE LandBild (
Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Landname, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE HighBild (
Highlight_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Highlight_ID, Bild_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Highlight_ID) REFERENCES Highlight (Highlight_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Primary Key Should always contain only one column and your foreign key should be in create a statement.

And I can able to solve the below query issues and rest of us, I cannot understand what you try to achieve

```
CREATE TABLE Bild ( Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Inhalt BLOB NOT NULL, Info VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (Bild_ID) );
CREATE TABLE Land ( Landname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TEXT TEXT NOT NULL, Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Landname), FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
CREATE TABLE Nutzer ( Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Nutzername VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, Passwort VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, Vorname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Nachname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Geburtstag DATETIME NOT NULL, Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Landname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID), FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID), FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
CREATE TABLE Highlight ( Highlight_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Titel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Info VARCHAR(255), Landname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Highlight_ID), FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land(Landname), FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
CREATE TABLE Rezension ( Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Titel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TEXT TEXT NOT NULL, Datum DATETIME NOT NULL, Bild_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Landname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Rezension_ID), FOREIGN KEY (Bild_ID) REFERENCES Bild (Bild_ID), FOREIGN KEY (Landname) REFERENCES Land (Landname), FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
CREATE TABLE RezSchreiben ( Nutzer_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Rezension_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Nutzer_ID, Rezension_ID), FOREIGN KEY (Nutzer_ID) REFERENCES Nutzer (Nutzer_ID), FOREIGN KEY (Rezension_ID) REFERENCES Rezension (Rezension_ID) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: You can make this code readable by editing, highlight the code block and ctrl k

Comment: 'Primary Key Should always contain only one column' - not true and the requirement for a foreign key is that the referencing column must have an index in the referenced table where the referenced column is the leftmost node of an index.